# Extract objects via object property

Tags: grails

Hello I have class Person and it's properties are object of type Job and String nam" ,now on the other hand the class Job has property :String jobname.I want to extract all the Person that have Job and the jobname is "admin" for example,how can I do it?

Comment: FOA you should add that little code blocks of your domains for better question readability..

Answer (score 0):

You should use **createCriteria()** method and **alias**.

```
def people = Person.createCriteria().list() {
    createAlias('job', 'j'),
    eq('j.jobname', 'admin')
}
```

Find out more about createCriteria [here](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html).